# Storyboard Constraint Issues: Half the height of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uilabel, constraints

I have a 4 labels in a storyboard, one large one at the top, and 3 smaller ones, with the bottom one centered in the middle(horizontally and vertically) like so:

[image: like so.]

I have a few constraints set already, like locking the top label at the top of the screen, and centering the bottom. **However, I do not know constraints I should use so that all four labels are equally spaced, AND the bottom label remains at the center.** I have played around with some constraints such as the spacing between the labels, but when I try to view this using a different screen size, everything is messed up:

[image: everything is messed up.]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is a `UIStackView`  with axis-> vertical , distribution -> fillEqually , so hook it's top ,leading , trailing to main view , drag the 4 labels inside it , and ctrl drag from the bottom most label to main view and select center vertically && horizontally

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, I have selected all my labels and embedded them into a stack view. However, I can't seem to resize the stack view. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: hook  bottom most label and it'll resize

Comment: Hmmm, I also had to hook the top label to the safe area. Does that seem right?

Answer (score 0):

You can made a trick here:

1. Set the top global label top constriants and center horizontally to super view.
2. Set the bottom label constraints center vertical and horizontally to super view.
3. Take three dummy view between label one-two, two-three, three-four.
4. Set constraints between these dummy view as equal height.
5. Then set top-bottom contraints between label and dummy view properly.
6. Set horizontal constraints of the label and dummy view. I have set as center horizontally.

Here I have attached the image: [image]

For better understanding I have colored the dummy view as light-gray. You can set it as clear.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! I did a little bit of research before going with @Sh_Khan's answer, and I found this alternative. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Thats my pleasure sir :) If my answer help you little bit then please upvote me.

Comment: I definitely would! Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote... :(

Comment: Ok no problem :)